# Derivative analog where perturbation is proportional to independent variable.

Tags: limits, derivatives

Recently I encountered a limit that reminded me a lot of the derivative and was wondering if this thing has a name. Basically, it is taking a difference quotient but the perturbation term is actually proportional to the original input. Suppose $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a multivariate function. Is there a name for the following expression:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f((1 + h) x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) - f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)}{h x_1}$$

It kind of reminded me of taking matrix derivatives (of various kinds) when you add an $h$. We can also easily modify this to be some sort of "total derivative"

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f((1+h) \vec x) - f(\vec x)}{h \Vert{\vec x \Vert}}$$
where $\vec x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.

Additionally, I am also not super sure how to interpret limits like these. If someone can tell me this expression's "intuitive" definition that would be great!

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, if you factor out the 1/x bit, that's just a partial derivative. Unless some field uses that a lot, I'd *guess* it doesn't have a name.

Comment: Doesn't your limit still perturb the $x_{1}$ variable by a value (in this case $hx_{1}$) and divide by that same value, while all other variables are fixed, as is done in the general definition of partial derivative $\partial f/\partial x_{1}$?